# Bad file descriptor error on MacOS Big Sur terminal

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, shell, macos-bigsur

I have just tried to install algs4 on MacOS Big Sur. However, it failed and after the installation process, my terminal keeps sending error messages every time I launch it:

> /Users/user/.zshrc:source:1: too many open files: /Users/user/.zshrc

> /Users/user/.zshrc:3: cannot duplicate fd 1: too many open files

> update_terminal_cwd:22: write error: bad file descriptor

If I type any words and press `enter`, then it will pass a message:

> update_terminal_cwd:22: write error: bad file descriptor

I have tried to reset the terminal, but it gave no effect. I also tried to type `exec >&2` and it only works temporarily.

Any help to fix this issue permanently is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a guess, but I suspect that your .zshrc (z-shell initialization script) is trying to run itself (which leads to it trying to run itself, which leads to it trying to run itself, ... forever, or at least until it runs out of some resource). It might run itself directly, or run something else that turns around and runs .zshrc. Specifically, it looks like line 1 of /Users/user/.zshrc might be the problem. What is that line?

Comment: I don't have any idea because that is the error message written every time I launch the terminal

Comment: You can open your .zshrc file in a text editor. [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) in my favorite for things like this, but in a pinch TextEdit will work. The trick is to press Command-Shift-Period in the Open dialog to get it to show invisible files (and Command-Shift-H to get to your home folder, if you're not already there).

Comment: I am unable to click my .zshrc file. Also there are .zshrc.save.1 and .zshrc.save.2 files in the folder. When I open it, there is a message saying "This operation couldn't be completed, because an error occurred. Permission denied (application error code: 100013)"

Comment: @GordonDavisson a bit old, but your answer fixed my concern. Thank you. You should write it as the answer to this question.